# How to call chruby from a ruby script

Tags: ruby, shell, chruby

I'm writing a ruby script to bootstrap a new macbook computer. I installed `chruby` and `ruby-install` via homebrew. If I call `chruby` from the command line it works.

```
$ chruby
* ruby-2.4.1
```

But if I call it from a ruby script like so.

```
def failing_function
  `chruby`
end

failing_function
```

I get this error

```
 No such file or directory - chruby (Errno::ENOENT)
```

As a test I tried this

```
def successful_function
    `ruby-install`
end

successful_function
```

And I get the same output for `ruby-install` in the script as I do the command line.

Anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to `chruby` within a Ruby script? Even if you `chruby` inside, the outer Ruby version will not change.

Comment: @FranklinYu I want to set the system wide ruby to a new version via chruby. I don't need the ruby version of the script itself to change. Does that answer your question?

Comment: So even after this Ruby script exits, you want the default Ruby version for new shell sessions to be the new Ruby?

Comment: Correct. OSX comes with ruby built in. However, it's frequently not up to date. With chruby I can easily get the most up to date ruby version, and even use different versions in different directories.

Comment: AFAIK this is not what `chruby` does. For example, if you want to change the default Ruby to 2.5.1, add `chruby 2.5.1` to your user profile. Running this command in a process will only change the Ruby version in *that process* (and sub-processes of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking deeper into this, turns out that `chruby` is not a proper binary but instead is a bash function that's added to the environment by calling `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh`. I ran a quick test by running `echo $SHELL` in a ruby console and it did show that it was using my zsh shell, so not sure why the full config was not loaded. In any case, I got it to work by doing this

```
def successful_function
  `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh && chruby`
end

successful_function
```